# Latextit behaves crazy

Tags: latexit

I have LaTeXIt in a Mac running High Sierra.
I cannot understand why a simple think like this:

\theta = 2\pi

does not display anything, but

\theta = 3\pi does.

Comment: What version of LaTeXiT and TeX are you using? I have no problems with either one (I don't see how LaTeXiT can even treat them differently) using LaTeXiT 2.12.0 and a fully updated TeX Live 2018 installed by MacTeX-2018.

Comment: Is 2.11.0 and TexShop 4.17

Comment: But updated and it is the same.

Comment: Try deleting the auxliary files and recompile. Tell us exactly what you do step by step and please give a _complete_ but minimal example which reproduces your problem.